# Are these two iterative approaches to find closest pair equivalent in any way?

Tags: algorithm, list, loops, closest, equivalent

```
myList = [500, 700, 1000, 1400, 2000, 6000]
target_value = 1600
diff = sys.maxint
```

Two iterations to find pair of numbers closest to sum. First approach using nested loop to check inner and outer values. Second approach traversing from left and right outside in. Assume list is sorted.

```
def iteration1(myList,target_value):
    for o in range(0, len(myList)):
        for i in range(o, len(myList)):
            if (myList[o] + myList[i]) - target_value < diff:
                # do something
            if ((myList[o] + myList[i]) > target_value):
                # go to next loop iteration
                continue
    return #something
```

```
def iteration2(myList,target_value):
    l = 0, r = len(myList)
    while l < r:
        if (myList[l] + myList[r]) - target_value < diff:
            # do something 
        if ((myList[l] + myList[r]) < target_value):
        # move to greater values
            l += 1
        else:
        # move to lesser values
            r -= 1
    return #something
```

Comment: oops, edited out typo

Comment: What makes you think they could be equivalent? Do you understand how they work?

Comment: In both methods, looks like they are going over every combination of pairs in the list without repeating and returning something at the bottom when their loop ends

Comment: The second algorithm definitely does not go over all possible combination of pairs. Notice that in each iteration, either `l` is incremented or `r` is decremented. Therefore, this can happen at most `n - 1` times before `l` and `r` meet, where `n` is the number of array elements. This makes the algorithm much faster than the first algorithm. Note that it requires the array to be sorted beforehand. This is a classical example for the two pointers approach, so look it up and you'll find plenty of explanations of that.

Comment: In the latter if the statement was `while l <= r:`, would it cover at most `n` times possibilities? Looking for a case where it goes beyond `n - 1`

Comment: Yes, if you want it to allow using the same number twice. Also, there is a possible bug where `r` is initialized to `len(myList)` instead of `len(myList) - 1`.